# How to manage the security on the list?

Tags: security

How do I manage the security on a list so one group of users can modify all the fields of an item and one group users can only modify some of the fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ways I've worked around this in the past have been to create custom data view web parts that users can edit items in.  The select group of individuals that can only edit certain fields get pointed to this DVWP that only has the fields available for them to edit, whereas full edit members get taken to the default list or web part page with a view to the list.

SharePoint doesn't provide a clean way to restrict columns specifically one group of users.  Bamboo had a feature for 2007 called Column Level Security, I'm not sure if that has been ported to 2010 or not and if there are alternatives from other 3rd party developers.

Answer (score 1):

As PirateEric said, SharePoint does not provide explicit way to set permission on columns. Tools like [SharePoint Column View Permission](http://www.sharepointboost.com/columnpermission.html) can help you set permission on columns both for SharePoint 2010 and 2007.

That being said, as far as I know, all those third party tools are hide column on UI level, not 100% waterproof.